# Calculation if checkbox checked in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two lists of objects named userList and itemList like this:

vm.userList

```
[{"id":1,"name":"apple","price":123},
 {"id":2,"name":"microsoft","price":100},
 {"id":3,"name":"eucerin","price":94}]
```

vm.itemList

```
[{"name":"apple","total_price":200},
```

and I use ng-repeat to repeat checkboxes using the values in that list like this

```
<div>{{vm.totalPrice}}</div>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.allSelected" ng-change="vm.toggleAll()" />

<tr ng-repeat="item in vm.userList track by $index">
   <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" ng-change="vm.updateCheck(item, $index)" /></td>
   <td>{{ item.name}}</td>
   <td>{{ item.price}}</td>
   <td>{{ item.rest}}</td>
</tr>
```

I need when I click on vm.updateCheck() to be updated {{vm.total Price}} (if I click on the Apple with price 123 my new total price will be 77 (200-123) and my item.rest for this will be 0) and continue for each object in vm.userList.

If my total price less then price in vm.userList ( {{vm.total Price}} will be set on 0 and in {{ item.rest}} I need enroll difference diference {{vm.totalPrice}} - {{item.price}}).

If my total price 0 and I want to click on checkbox need got some alert with some message

Controller

```
vm.toggleAll = function() {
        angular.forEach(vm.userList, function(item) {
                item.checked = vm.allSelected;
        });
    };

vm.listPrice = vm.itemList.price

vm.updateCheck = function(item){
        if(vm.allSelected===true){
            vm.allSelected = false;
        }
        var price = vm.listPrice;

        if(price <= item.price){
            item.rest = parseInt(item.price - price);
        }else{
            item.rest = 0;
        }

        angular.forEach(vm.userList, function(item) {
            if(item.checked){
                price = parseInt(price - item.price);
            }else{
                item.rest = 0;
            }
        });

        vm.totalPrice = price >0 ? price : 0;
```

please i need help, I am new on Anguar

Comment: code is included

Comment: Be aware that the `vm.updateCheck()` function will be invoked both when  a checkbox is checked and when a  checkbox is unchecked.  So the calculation of `vm.allSelected` is erroneous.